# PostgreSQL/PGAdmin4 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique

PostgreSQL/PGAdmin4 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

This is the ‘schema’ I’m trying to code into PGAdmin4/Postgresql:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWjSO.jpg

I was able to convert all tables, except “QUALIFICATIONS”.

I tried to process the following query:

```
create table REGISTRATION(
    StudentID int,
    SectionNo int,
    Semester varchar(16),
    foreign key(StudentID) references Student(StudentID),
    foreign key (SectionNo, Semester) references Section(SectionNo, Semester),
    primary key(studentID, SectionNo, Semester)
    );
```

I received the following message:
    ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "section"

These are the foreign and primary I have in the table SECTION

PKEY: i.imgur.com/BcUNKug.jpg

FKEY: i.imgur.com/D8B8hRW.jpg

Code of SECTION table:

```
CREATE TABLE class_scheduling_01.section
(
sectionno integer NOT NULL,
semester character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
courseid character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT section_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sectionno, semester, courseid),
CONSTRAINT section_sectionno_key UNIQUE (sectionno),
CONSTRAINT section_courseid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (courseid)
    REFERENCES class_scheduling_01.course (courseid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I additionally ran the command: ALTER TABLE section ADD UNIQUE (sectionno);

Since none of the attributes seemed to be repeating itself.

Despite all this I’m getting: 
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "section" Query returned successfully in 642 msec.

Edit: I've gone back to the COURSE table and made courseID a unique constraint. I still get the same message. SECTION table has a composite primary key made up of 3 columns. As seen in the first picture linked, out of all the values, only SECTION.sectionno is the only column with unique/non-repeating values.

2nd edit: I decided to create the table "REGISTRATION" one step at a time, and make the foreign keys last with alter table command.

I was able to make the columns StudentID andd SectionNo foreign keys to their respective columns. When I tried to make REGISTRATION.semester a foreign key to SECTION.semester I got the error message again.
    alter table REGISTRATION add foreign key (semester) references section(semester);

As seen in the image I linked Semester value, is repeated; despite this, am I still required to make it unique? Or do I make a unique command assigning all 3 columns (of SECTION) together as unique, instead of just 1? If so, how?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Is there a way for me to generate a code of the entire schema without having to go through each indvidual tables (5 of 6 so far), and doing Script → 'create script'?

Comment: The table referenced in your first script is called Section, but the actual table starts with a lower case "s": section. Best to keep everything lowercase in Postgresql. Your columns are also incorrectly cased based on the actual column definitions.

Comment: SQL is case insensitive. I wrote it that that way to make it easier to spot typos.

Comment: It would be better to keep the casing the same. You will be prone to error that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
foreign key (SectionNo, Semester) references Section(SectionNo, Semester),
```

requires that there be a unique constraint on the pair of columns SectionNo and Semester.

```
CREATE TABLE class_scheduling_01.section
(
sectionno integer NOT NULL,
semester character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
courseid character varying(16) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT section_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sectionno, semester, courseid),
CONSTRAINT section_sectionno_key UNIQUE (sectionno),
CONSTRAINT section_courseid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (courseid)
    REFERENCES class_scheduling_01.course (courseid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
-- Unique constraint on the pair
CONSTRAINT your_constraint_name UNIQUE (SectionNo, Semester)
);
```

That change should let these SQL statements succeed. I didn't check to see whether that's a good idea.

> SQL is case insensitive.

I understand what you mean, but this is a bad way to think about it.

PostgreSQL folds unquoted *identifiers* to lowercase. So PostgreSQL would treat the *identifiers* `SQL`, `Sql`, and `sql` as if they were all `sql`. A quoted or delimited identifier, like `"Select"` always refers to either a table or a column; it's never interpreted as a keyword. Quoted identifiers are case-sensitive. You can't successfully refer to the table `"Select"` as `select`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upv ote your post.
ALTER TABLE class_scheduling_01.section
    ADD CONSTRAINT section_sectionno_semester_key UNIQUE (sectionno, semester);
Then
ALTER TABLE class_scheduling_01.registration
    ADD CONSTRAINT registration_studentid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (studentid)
    REFERENCES class_scheduling_01.student (studentid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;

Comment: Correction:
ALTER TABLE class_scheduling_01.section ADD CONSTRAINT section_sectionno_semester_key UNIQUE (sectionno, semester)
Then:
ALTER TABLE class_scheduling_01.registration
    ADD CONSTRAINT registration_sectionno_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sectionno, semester)
    REFERENCES class_scheduling_01.section (sectionno, semester) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;